# Por que incluir Chart.js em snippet causa erro na janela de resposta?

Tags: bug, status-intencional, respostas

Respondi uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/235298/mudan%C3%A7a-de-cor-no-gr%C3%A1fico-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1-funcionando) recentemente sobre Chart.js e incluí o código e as referências para gerar o gráfico na execução do código.

Ao clicar no botão "Executar", o gráfico é gerado, mas aparece um erro na janela de renderização.

Esse é um **problema da janela de resposta ou um erro no código**?

[image: Erro presuposto]

Comment: *Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from **accessing a cross-origin** frame.
    at Object.helpers.addEvent*. Acredito (?) que seja relacionado ao [CORS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/145490/66203)

Comment: Acho que pode ter relação sim. Provavelmente por conta do CDN utilizado. Mas mesmo assim a biblioteca é acessada e a função é chamada normalmente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O *Stack Snippet* usa [***sandbox***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) por questões de segurança com os *dados dos usuários* que acessarem vossa resposta.

O **navegador** é quem bloqueia certas interações, portanto a linha 6016 do arquivo https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.js tenta acessar diretamente `iframe.contentWindow` o que ocasiona o problema:

```
helpers.addEvent(iframe, 'load', function() {
AQUI ---> helpers.addEvent(iframe.contentWindow || iframe, 'resize', notify);
```

Não é um problema com o site, mas sim com a lib `Chart.js`.

Comment: Será que poderíamos gerar uma versão desta biblioteca sem essa parte do código, para incluída no formulário de inserção do código HTML/javascript/css de respostas? Isso daria maior liberdade para criação de gráficos nas respostas. Se sim, como podemos fazer essa sugestão ao pessoal de DEV do site? Sou novo por aqui e não conheço.

Comment: @AlexandreCavaloti é opção sua, você pode copiar o conteúdo todo da lib e postar dentro do snippet com os ajustes devidos na linha com problema, e então usar a opção hide na parte da lib e na parte html colocar com a tag <script> com parte executável que caberia ao código da resposta.

Comment: @AlexandreCavaloti outra opção é não usar o Stack Snippet, ao invés disto apenas poste o código e use um serviço a parte como o jsfiddle, claro que nada lhe impede de postar isto como um "issue" no github do chart.js: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/new ;)